# Propagate an object to a subclass post creation, contingent on criteria

Tags: java, design-patterns

I know that the factory method is a suitable design pattern for creating objects without the client needing to know which concrete class the object needs to be.  But that assumes that the factory will know the criteria before the object is created

However, my case is a little different. I need to create an object into the superclass or what would normally be an abstract class.  Once the object is constructed (AND ONLY THEN), logic can be applied to determine which category it can belong to, i.e. the subclass.

Imagine that you are a large company recruiting talent from a college.  Kids don't really know what they wanna do and you will assign them positions after training.  So at first someone is an `Employee` and then six months down the road they evolve into a `Programmer`, `QA`, `Analyst` etc. depending on their proclivities.  So I need to propagate the `Employee` class after creation into `Programmer`, `QA`, `Analyst` etc.  Then each will continue to be `Employee` but also each will have their own distinct properties.  Upon initiation, they are all just `Employee`, so Employee cannot be abstract.

I was thinking to have a subclass creation method returning the subclass but that would mean there are two instances, the initial superclass and finally the subclass that I want, at which point I no longer need the superclass.  I understand I can set the parent object to null and GC it once the subclass has been created but I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this, i.e. a design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

> Once the object is constructed (AND ONLY THEN), logic can be applied to determine which category it can belong to, i.e. the subclass.

That's simply not going to happen. Unlike your analogy, objects in Java never change type over their lifetime.

If you could explain in concrete terms *why* you think you need this, we may be able to help - but I suspect it will *either* come down to composition *or* it will be a factory class, where the factory will do some processing to start with, and pass the results of that processing to the appropriate subclass constructor to avoid the data having to be recomputed.

Comment: Jon, I think the Employee vs evolution into Programmer some time into the life of Employee is the best I could exemplify this

Comment: Processing to determing the criteria before object creation is EXACTLY what i would like to avoid.  Essentially, i want to create a Human and evolve THE SAME INSTANCE into an Automechanic 25 years later without necessarily creating a new instance

Comment: @foampile: Well no it's not, because you could tell us the *real problem you're facing*. If you're actually modelling an employee, I'd use composition: each `Employee` has a `Role` property, which could be Programmer etc.

Comment: @foampile: You've said you want to avoid it, but you haven't given any concrete *coding* reason why. You've only given an example of the real world, which doesn't actually match up with how Java objects work. Your aim simply *can't* be achieved in Java - objects just don't change type, no matter how much you want them to.

Comment: I was thinking of that but each Role has to have proprietary methods, i.e. be a different class

Comment: @foampile: So do that, if you want it to. But clearly you have some concrete problem in mind that you're not willing to share, and I very much doubt that it's actually modelling employees, or that you need to wait for 25 years before discovering the new type. At this point I'm afraid I'm off to bed...

Comment: can't be done, OK.  i understand that.

Comment: you are right, it is not modeling employees

Comment: have a good night and thanks for the discussion